# Vue: Updating data on child component via ref not updating DOM

Tags: vue.js

Inside my Child Component, I have this object in my data:

```
export default {
  
  name: 'BillingStripeForm',
  components: {
      Alert
  },

  data() {
      return {
        paymentFormError: {},

  }
...
}
```

And inside this child component, I'm using another component to display an error message based on a condition:

`<Alert v-if="paymentFormError.description" :description="paymentFormError.description" :title="paymentFormError.title" type="error"></Alert>`

The form logic is submitted by the parent component.

Since I need the child's data, I've given it a `ref`:

```
<billing-stripe-form ref="billingForm">
```

When I submit the form, I'm grabbing the component via `refs` and its data:

```
let billingFormComponent = this.$refs.billingForm;
```

Now I will manipulate the data on the child like so:

```
billingFormComponent.paymentFormError.description = "some error";
billingFormComponent.paymentFormError.title = "Oops! Something went wrong.";
```

```
// called on form submit
submitForm() {
  let billingFormComponent = this.$refs.billingForm;

  let billingAccount = billingFormComponent.billingForm;
  let stripe = billingFormComponent.stripe;
  let stripeElements = billingFormComponent.stripeElements;
  
  // just testing errors regardless
  billingFormComponent.paymentFormError.description = "some error";
  billingFormComponent.paymentFormError.title = "Oops! Something went wrong.";
}
```

Looking above, you will see that my `Alert` is shown if the object has a `description`, which I've just set.

In vue dev tools, I can see that the data is changing correctly. The child component data reflects what my `submitForm` function changes it to. But the DOM doesn't update. The `Alert` is not shown.

If I refresh the page and manually add the data via Vue Dev Tools, my Alert does show.

So how can I update a child's data via `refs` on the Parent, and have it be reactive and update the DOM?

Comment: Have you tried Vue.set(billingFormComponent.paymentFormError, 'description', 'some error') ?

Comment: That worked, thanks! Didn't know about `Vue.set`

Comment: If you'd like to leave an answer, I can select yours as best

Comment: No problem, thanks mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update some part of Vue state in a reactive way, use Vue.set(this.data.object, 'propertyKey', 'value'). In your case:

```
Vue.set(billingFormComponent.paymentFormError, 'description', 'some error');
```